# Flutter stateful widget is not updating while calling from Navigation drawer

Tags: flutter, stateful

I am trying to update my stateful widget of my class while calling it from Navigation Drawer. stateless widget are being updated when they are called from Navigation Drawer. Here is my Navigation drawer from where I am calling 'Fragment First'.

```
class DrawerItem {
String title;
IconData icon;
DrawerItem(this.title, this.icon);
 }

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 final drawerItems = [
   new DrawerItem("First Fragment", Icons.rss_feed),
   new DrawerItem("Second Fragment", Icons.local_pizza),
   new DrawerItem("Third Fragment", Icons.info)
 ];

 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return new HomePageState();
 }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 int _selectedDrawerIndex = 0;

  _getDrawerItemWidget(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
  case 0:

    return new FirstFragmen(pos);
  case 1:

    return new FirstFragmen(pos);
  case 2:

    return new FirstFragmen(pos);

  default:
    return new Text("Error");
  }
}

 _onSelectItem(int index) {
   setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = index);
   Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   List<Widget> drawerOptions = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < widget.drawerItems.length; i++) {
    var d = widget.drawerItems[i];
     drawerOptions.add(
       new ListTile(
      leading: new Icon(d.icon),
      title: new Text(d.title),
      selected: i == _selectedDrawerIndex,
      onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
    )
  );
}

return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    // here we display the title corresponding to the fragment
    // you can instead choose to have a static title
    title: new Text(widget.drawerItems[_selectedDrawerIndex].title),
  ),
  drawer: new Drawer(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: new Text("John Doe"), accountEmail: null),
        new Column(children: drawerOptions)
      ],
    ),
     ),
     body: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex),
   );
    }
 }
```

Here is Fragment First:

```
class FirstFragment extends StatefulWidget {

 int pos;
 FirstFragment(this.pos);
@override
 _FirstFragmentState createState() => new _FirstFragmentState(pos);
 }

 class _FirstFragmentState extends State<FirstFragment> {
 int pos;
 _FirstFragmentState(this.pos);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  // TODO: implement build
  return new Center(
  child: new Text("Hello Fragment $pos"), >printing 'pos' only. It remains 
  > same all time when new class is called. 
  );
 }
}
```

if I am using stateless widget then its being updated, but stateful widget is not being updated. I've tried to debug using breakpoints but  _FirstFragmentState class is called only once. Is there any way to redraw all widgets when its called second time.

Comment: `setState(() {})`

Comment: this is not working I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is created once and then shared for multiple instances of your widget. Since you're taking `pos` in the state constructor, it's not being updated later when widgets change.

One way to solve this would be to remove the `pos` in your `_FirstFragmentState`, and reference the `pos` in `FirstFragment` directly. You can access it through the `widget` field of your state class.

```
class _FirstFragmentState extends State<FirstFragment> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Center(
     child: new Text("Hello Fragment ${widget.pos}"), // -> use pos from FirstFragment
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can we call setState() method from FirstFragment class directly?

Comment: Hm not sure I understand. Why can't you call setState()?

Comment: setState() can be called from _FirstFragmentState so when I am returning same class again then I can't call setState method.

Comment: I don't follow. What happens when you "return to the same class" and call setState?

Comment: I am calling it as FirstFragment(this.pos){ setState();  } I am getting run time error that setState can't be called from constructor

Comment: Even if you were allowed to do that, the state has just been created, you need to setState when state is changed, not on creation.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172696/discussion-between-ammy-kang-and-edman).